# How to add a shortcode for an image in the following function

Tags: php, images, shortcode

This is a function by [Tobias Keller](https://tobier.de/prg-pattern-in-wordpress-implementieren/) for PRG Pattern Link Masking where **title shortcode** is link text. How то add **image shortcode** alternatively instead text ?

```
$use_prg = new prg_pattern();

class prg_pattern {

    public function __construct() {
        /* load redirect function */
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'prg_get_and_redirect' ) );

        /* add shortcode function */
        add_shortcode( 'prgpattern', array( $this, 'prg_pattern_form' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the shortcode attributes and returns the html form
     *
     * @param   array   shortcode attributes
     * @return  string  HTML-Form with shortcode attributes
     * */
    public function prg_pattern_form( $atts ){

        /* get shortcode attributes */
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'slug' => 'noFoo',
                'title' => 'noBob',
                'extern' => 'false',
                'newtab' => 'false'
            ), $atts, 'prgpattern' );

        /* check if user wants external or internal redirect */
        if ( $atts['extern'] == 'true' ) {
            /* redirect to external url */
            $redirect_slug = esc_url( $atts['slug'] );
        } else {
            /* redirect to internal url */
            $redirect_slug = esc_url( home_url() . '/' . strtolower( $atts['slug'] ) );
        }

        /* form output */
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <?php if( $atts['newtab'] == 'true' ): ?>
            <form method="POST" target="_blank">
        <?php else: ?>
            <form method="POST">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <button class="noLink" type="submit" name="prgpattern" value="<?php echo $redirect_slug; ?>"><?php echo $atts['title']; ?></button>
            </form>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Redirects to target url if url is set
     *
     * @param   string      The target url of prg_pattern_form()
     * @return  redirect    Redirects to the target url
     */
    public function prg_get_and_redirect(){
        /* check if target url is set */
        if ( isset( $_POST['prgpattern'] ) ) {
            /* escaping url again */
            $slug = esc_url( $_POST['prgpattern'] );
            /* redirect to target url */
            wp_redirect( $slug );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific, it's not clear what you mean by use an image shortcode instead of text, I don't see which text you're referring to, or what you mean by an image shortcode. Do you mean you want to give it the URL to an image? Where would that image appear? Do you mean instead of the title? If so should it not be as straightforward as changing the part where it `echo`'s the title to instead echo an `<img` tag? Reading the original article it looks like the PRG practice would be penalised as not being accessible, canonical URLs should already prevent duplicate content penalties

Comment: Yes,  **nstead of the title**

Sample shortcode from this function is:

**[prgpattern slug="https://somedomain.com" title="Click Me"]**

and the result is simple button with text "Click Me"

( With CSS I override the appearance of the button and get only a text link, never mind )

So, instead of "Click Me" I want an image - banner. 

I can't put image in shortcode